# Excel VBA code to attach files in QC Test Cases

Tags: vba, excel, hp-quality-center

I have a tool that capture screenshots of the application that we test at our workplace. Now once I complete my testing of a particular test case or scenarios, we attach the screenshot that we have taken to HP Quality Center manually.

I want to automate this and make my tool to upload the word document to a test in QC Test Lab. Is this possible? If Yes, How can we do this in Excel VBA?

Operations that we need to perform would be as below:

1. Connect to QC project with login credentials, domain & project details
2. Pick a file(s) from a local folder
3. Upload a file(s) to QC Test Lab, specific test case

I used the below code, but getting error in that code. I marked it in the code below, please check below :

```
Dim intTestID, FldPath, TestSetName, i
Dim TestSetFact, tsTreeMgr, tSetFolder, TestSetsList, theTestSet
Dim TestSetIdentifier, TSTestFact, TestSetTestsList, testInstanceF, aFilter
Dim lst, tstInstance

intTestID = "8968"

FldPath = TextBox3.Text '"Root\ProjFold\Release1\BRD"
TestSetName = ComboBox3.Text '"BRD" '

Set Connection = CreateObject("TDApiOle80.TDConnection")
Connection.InitConnectionEx Sheet2.Range("B1").Value2
Connection.Login TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text
Connection.Connect ComboBox1.Text, ComboBox2.Text

Set TestSetFact = Connection.TestSetFactory
Set tsTreeMgr = Connection.TestSetTreeManager

Set tSetFolder = tsTreeMgr.NodeByPath(FldPath)
Set TestSetsList = tSetFolder.FindTestSets(TestSetName)
Set theTestSet = TestSetsList.Item(1)
TestSetIdentifier = theTestSet.ID
i = 0
Set TSTestFact = theTestSet.TSTestFactory
Set TestSetTestsList = TSTestFact.NewList("")

Set testInstanceF = Connection.TSTestFactory
Set aFilter = testInstanceF.Filter

aFilter.Filter("TC_TEST_ID") = intTestID
Set lst = testInstanceF.NewList(aFilter.Text)
Set tstInstance = lst.Item(1)   <---------------- getting error here
MsgBox (tstInstance.Field("TS_Name"))
'tstInstance.Status = "Failed"
'tstInstance.Field("TC_STATUS") = Item1.Status '"Passed"
'tstInstance.Post
Dim RunF, runName, NewRun, runStepF, runlst, Item1, runStep2

MsgBox (tstInstance.Field("TS_Subject"))
Set RunF = tstInstance.RunFactory
runName = "Run_" & Month(Date) & "-" & Day(Date) & "_" & Hour(Now) & "-" & Minute(Now) &         "-" & Second(Now)
Set NewRun = RunF.AddItem(Null)
NewRun.Status = "Passed"
NewRun.Name = runName
NewRun.Post
NewRun.CopyDesignSteps
NewRun.Post
Set runStepF = NewRun.StepFactory
Set runlst = runStepF.NewList("")
For Each Item1 In runlst
      Set runStep2 = Item1
      runStep2.Status = "Passed" '
      runStep2.Field("ST_ACTUAL") = "As Expected"
      runStep2.Post
Next
'tstInstance.Refresh
tstInstance.Status = "Failed"

tstInstance.Post
Connection.DisconnectProject
Connection.ReleaseConnection
'Set QC = Nothing
Set Connection = Nothing
```

Comment: Does the returned list start with a zero index, rather than a 1? This can often be a little unexpected if you are used to arrays/collections/lists which are often defined to start at index one in VBA, but you are working working between VBA and other bits of code which start all arrays/lists/collections at index 0. Try `Set tstInstance = lst.Item(0) `?

Comment: Agree with @Orphid. Try starting your array at 0. I've had hassle using arrays to populate combo boxes because `Array(0)` had no value in it where I've started at 1

Answer (score 0):

The error is occurring because the array of objects is not returning. You need to check if the `Filter` gives you a list of results before assuming that `lst.Item(1)` exists.

For instance:

```
If lst.Count > 0 Then Set tstInstance = lst.Item(1)
```